# how can i get all winforms form border styles in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm new to C#, working through a tutorial.  I'm trying to add a border style to a combo box and I want to be able to retrieve all the possible border styles.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /*
        foreach (FormBorderStyle f in FormBorderStyle)
        {
        }
       */
        // This return only the current one.
        FormBorderStyle borderStyleEntry = this.FormBorderStyle;
        borderSelector.Items.Add(borderStyleEntry );
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean with *"retrieve all of the available"*? Have you checked the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hw8kes41.aspx)?

Comment: I read this page yea, what i mean retrieve all available is: in visual mode when i click on form, and in properties i look for form border style i have like 4-6 options (didnt) count. i want to create a combo box like this one. by getting all those border styles and add them to a combo box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FormBorderStyle` is an `Enum`. You need to `foreach` over the values of the `Enum`.

```
foreach (FormBorderStyle f in (FormBorderStyle[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(FormBorderStyle)))
{
    borderSelector.Items.Add(f.ToString());
}
```

For completeness, based on a comment by @elgonzo, the following shows how to get the `Enum` value back from the `String`.

```
private void borderSelector_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.FormBorderStyle = (FormBorderStyle)Enum.Parse(typeof(FormBorderStyle), borderSelector.SelectedItem.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can first convert the FormBorderStyle enum to `List<string>` and then set it as the datasource for the combobox.

```
List<string> values = Enum.GetNames(typeof(FormBorderStyle)).ToList();
comboBox1.DataSource = values;
```

Comment: Note, that if you want to get back the Enum values from the strings in the combobox, you will need to use Enum.Parse(...)